# Button on separate sheet Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button in Sheet3, but I want it to run the following Macro from Sheet1.  I continue to get an error when I run the following String.

```
Public Sub Blue()

    If Now() > Range("Sheet1!AL2") Then
        Range("Sheet1!AC2:AG2").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("Sheet1!AC15").Select
        Sheet1!.Paste
        Range("Sheet1!X2:AB2").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("Sheet1!AC2").Select
        Sheet1!.Paste
        Range("Sheet1!AC15:AG15").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("Sheet1!X2").Select
        Sheet1!.Paste
        Range("Sheet1!AL2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("Sheet1!AK2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Get rid of the exclamation point, i.e., `Sheet1.Paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using select cut and paste

Instead try this

```
Range("Sheet1!AC15").value = Range("Sheet1!AC2:AG2").value
```